# Where can I find friendly strings for SQL Server versions?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, windows

The friendly string for **9.00.4035.00** is **SQL Server 2005 SP3 Express Edition**. I would like to convert version numbers to string by accessing only registry or a dictionary. Can I find a list?

Comment: Please could you explain a little more as it is not obvious to me exactly what you require?

Comment: I think that you are confusing the Version Numbers with the Edition.  there are (relatively) independent things.

Answer (score 3):

Steve Jones maintains build lists over at SQLServerCentral

The SQL2005 list is [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Administration/2960/)

The SQL2008 list is [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2008/63491/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [SERVERPROPERTY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx) method.

### EDIT 1:

And, I don't think you can get the whole string directly from the registry. You will have to gather the information from different registry hives. One, for example, is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\InstalledInstances`.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you a nice overview of all the version-related info in SQL Server:

```
SELECT  
    SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') as 'Product Version', 
    SERVERPROPERTY('productlevel') as 'Patch Level',  
    SERVERPROPERTY('edition') as 'Product Edition',
    SERVERPROPERTY('buildclrversion') as 'CLR Version',
    SERVERPROPERTY('collation') as 'Default Collation',
    SERVERPROPERTY('instancename') as 'Instance',
    SERVERPROPERTY('lcid') as 'LCID',
    SERVERPROPERTY('servername') as 'Server Name'
```

Output will be something like:

```
10.0.2531.0 SP1 Developer Edition (64-bit)  v2.0.50727  
   Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL    1033    (machinename)
```

Marc

Answer (score 0):

The Product Support KB page at [How to identify your SQL Server version and edition](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185) has the 'official' version info for any build number released.